# "Unknown SDK home path" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I had to switch the user account on a Windows 10 PC (a very long story).  Now, I am unable to open Android app projects as Android projects.  I cannot even create a new Android project.  I think that I have found the culprit, but do not know how to remedy it.

Start Android Studio > Configure (under Quick Start) > Project Defaults > Project Structure > SDKs under Platform Settings:

[image]

I do not know why it shows Unknown SDK home path.  This is Android Studio 3.0

Could anyone offer a tip on how to deal with this?

**[Update (2017-11-27)]:**
The problem has been solved by:

File > Settings > plugins > Enable "Android SPK Support" and a few other relevant plugins.

Do not know why there were disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think as it is another User on Windows, Maybe the environmental variables path setting might be in User Variables rather than on a System Variables.
Because System Variables meant for all Users whereas User Variables are restricted based on User.

Comment: Thanks. Which variable should I look into?

Comment: My guess is like to make sure you are using a JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to the correct path.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is a system variable pointing to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92".  It is correct.